# localtest.me’s server IP address could not be found

Tags: iis, dns

I've attempted to set up a test binding through IIS to localtest.me, but it's not resolving to my local IP address. My understanding of localtest.me is that it should resolve automatically. In Chrome is get the error message:

> blog-test.localtest.me’s server IP address could not be found.

And when pinging blog-test.localtest.me I get the following error:

```
Ping request could not find host blog-test.localtest.me. Please check the name and try again.
```

In IIS I have a site that's bound to blog-test.localtest.me with the following settings:
[image: IIS Settings]

Everything I've read online advises that localtest.me should resolve automatically? Is this the case or is there setup step I'm missing?

Comment: It is not a total surprise. That mechanism is not working everywhere. Run `nslookup blog-test.localtest.me` at command prompt and you should see if your current DNS settings support it or not (services like Google DNS support it well).

Comment: Thanks - yeah I did the lookup and no A records are set

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add this entry in your host file locally, and it will work.

On windows machine - `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

On *nix machine - `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you didn't register the domain in either DNS or hosts file.

1.So if you are in an AD environment, please add a CNAME blog-test.localtest.me in your local DNS **Forward lookup zone**.

2.If you are going to access the website from public domain, then please purchase the domian from domain provider and point it to Server's public IP.

3.If you just want to access the website locally, please add the domain to hosts file.

The hosts record would looks like:

127.0.0.1    blog-test.localtest.me